# Калоши или галоши?

Tags: орфография, недопустимая-метка

В литературе можно встретить оба варианта. Какой из них правильный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, допустимы оба варианта. Однако форма "калоши" считает устаревшей. Впрочем, стоит заметить, что этимологически правильно говорить именно "галоши", поскольку это слово произошло от французского "**g**aloshes".

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта правильны. Калоша закрепилось в выражениях "сесть в калошу" и "старая калоша" (о судне). Поэтому говорить о предпочтительности не приходится.

Касательно происходения.
Во французском нет слова **galoshes** - и вряд ли может быть.
Есть **galoches**, хотя чаще калоши называют caoutchoucs.
Но главное, что есть немецкое Kaloschen - от которого вернее всего и произощло русское.